# Radio button allow multiple selections

Tags: javascript

Can the radio button be implemented like a checkbox button? I hope radio buttion can multiple selection. Do not use checkbox button!

**I want the effect as follows:**

```
[0,1,2]
```

```js
function clickButton() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      console.log(radios[i].value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="Selection">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0" /> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" /> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" /> Other<br>
  <button onclick="clickButton();return false;">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: with one radio button (same name) you can have only value

Comment: why do you need radio button to perform as checkbox?

Comment: Why not use checkbox?

Comment: You can customize checkboxes and radio buttons https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp
So you can have checkbox look like radio to meet you need

Comment: Because of my project needs. If not, change the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give different names to the radio buttons, then grab the tags by tag name and push the values to an array.

**PS**: The correct way is to checkboxes because they are designed to do this functionality

**Working Demo**

```js
function clickButton() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var checked = [];
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      checked.push(radios[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(checked);
}
```

```html
<form id="Selection">
  <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="0" /> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender2" value="1" /> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender3" value="2" /> Other<br>
  <button onclick="clickButton();return false;">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When you click, turn on or off.

Comment: Yeah you can but again checkboxes are used for that. You can use this logic as well

Comment: If this helped please do upvote and accept as answer!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to allow this would be to have unique names. The radio button is specifically meant for single select. If you want multi-select ability, then that is what checkboxes would be for.

```
<form id="Selection">
  <input type="radio" name="gender_male" value="0" /> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender_female" value="1" /> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender_other" value="2" /> Other<br>
  <button onclick="clickButton();return false;">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use different names for your radio buttons -

```js
function clickButton() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('gender');
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      console.log(radios[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="Selection">
  <input type="radio" class="gender" name="genderMale" value="0" /> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" class="gender" name="genderFemale" value="1" /> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" class="gender" name="genderOther" value="2" /> Other<br>
  <button onclick="clickButton();return false;">submit</button>
</form>
```